# Crystal Reports - Dynamic Grouping depending on Summary field

Tags: crystal-reports

Trying to group dynamically depending on the field I sum using Summary. Example: table looks like

> Person  |  Date 1  |  Category 1  |  Date 2  |  Category 2  |
>
> John    | 1/1/2010 |  minor       | 1/1/2015 |  major       |
>
> Paul    | 1/1/2010 |  minor       | 1/1/2015 |  minor       |

I want to group dynamically by [major; minor] using sum of entries, like:

> |   1/1/2010  |   1/1/2015  |
>
> major  |   0         |   1         |
>
> minor  |   2         |   1         |

This is a simple example but there could be dynamic categories from the input dataset, not just 2 hardcoded values.

Not sure if this is possible in Crystal Reports.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it with the cross tab. I hate it, but it does the work. +1 for showing your data.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure about the cross tab. I decided to alter the dataset (put the complexity there) to allow Crystal's grouping to be easy.

Comment: I think you made a great decision!